# Jquery Menu icon changes only works after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a 'slide toggle menu' and I would like that the menu icon changes to 'close' every time the menu icon is clicked to open, and goes back to normal every time the menu icon is clicked to close. But it works only when I reload the page. After that, the icon is always the same: normal (not X).

Can you help me to find the problem?

```js
/* Mobile navigation */

$(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 980) {
    var nav = $('.js--mobile-nav');
    nav.hide();
  }
});

$('.js--mobile-nav-icon').click(function() {
  var nav = $('.js--mobile-nav');
  var icon = $('.js--mobile-nav-icon i');

  nav.slideToggle(200);

  if (icon.hasClass('icon ion-md-rainy')) {
    icon.addClass('icon ion-md-restaurant');
    icon.removeClass('icon ion-md-rainy');
  } else {
    icon.addClass('icon ion-md-rainy');
    icon.removeClass('icon ion-md-restaurant');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sec1" id="sec1">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo-img"><img src="img/logo_small.png" alt="Logo Thais Fachini" class="logo-img"></div>
    <!-- Sticky Navigation -->
    <div class="logo-img-sticky">
      <a href="#sec1"><img src="img/logo_small.png" alt="Logo Thais Fachini" class="logo-img-sticky"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-name">
      <h1>THAÍS FACHINI</h1>
      <p>Nutrition for Life</p>
    </div>
    <!-- Sticky Navigation -->
    <div class="logo-name-sticky">
      <h1>THAÍS FACHINI</h1>
      <p>Nutrition for Life</p>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <!-- Mobile Navigation --><a class="mobile-nav-icon js--mobile-nav-icon"><i class="icon ion-ios-menu"></i></a>
      <nav class="js--mobile-nav">
        <a href="#about" class="header-link">Sobre</a>
        <a href="#howitworks" class="header-link">Como funciona</a>
        <a href="#signup" class="header-link">Assinar</a>
        <a href="#" class="header-link">Cliente</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Put the `click()` handler inside the `$(function() { ... })` block

Comment: And what is supposed to do? Keep the state after reloading the page?

Comment: Hi Thanh, it's supposed to show the 'icon-rainy' when the menu is closed (or clicked to close), and show the 'icon-restaurant' when the menu is opened (or clicked to open).

Answer (score 0):

I end up changing the code like this (I thought it was because of hasClass wasn't recognized). The code works.

```
$(function() {
      var menu = false;

        if ($(window).width() < 980){
            var nav = $('.js--mobile-nav');
            nav.hide();
        }

        $('.js--mobile-nav-icon').click(function() {
          var nav = $('.js--mobile-nav');
          var icon = $('.js--mobile-nav-icon i');

          nav.slideToggle(200);

          if (menu) { 
              icon.removeClass('icon ion-ios-close');
              icon.addClass('icon ion-ios-menu');
          } else {
            icon.removeClass('icon ion-ios-menu');
            icon.addClass('icon ion-ios-close');
          }        
          menu = !menu;
      });
    });
```